# Blank response from UrlFetchApp in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to test the endpoints of an API and all the responses return blank with no errors.

I've tested using curl and the response actually has data in:

```py
curl --request GET https://myapiurl.com/endpoint --header "authorization: bearer TOKEN"
```

Here's the segment of GAS code. The token property is set when I run a POST call to retrieve it, it expires after a while:

```js
  var url = 'https://myapiurl.com/endpoint';
  var token = 'bearer TOKEN';
  var headers = {
    'authorization': token
  };
  var options = {
    'headers' : headers
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
```

The response should be a JSON object with a full list of keys/values. The response from curl is exactly what it should be, but the GAS version is blank, no errors.

I am completely at a loss, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have a look if this helps you:  https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/third-party-apis

Comment: In the curl request you provided, you perform a get request. If you want perform a POST request, your options should include the method, content type and the payload you want to post: `var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  payload: JSON.stringify(YOUR PAYLOAD)
};`

Comment: Sorry, the mention of POST is confusing. I am trying to perform get requests, the POST request I mentioned was to retrieve the token, save it as a variable then perform get requests with it. The line setting the token variable is usually
`var token = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('token');` but I changed it to show that the curl and the UrlFetchApp requests were both exactly the same

Comment: `headers` is a key word and goes without quotes:  `var myHeaders = {
    'authorization': token  }; 
var options = {
    headers : myHeaders
  };`