# Why am I getting an empty response back from UrlFetchApp in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

I am trying to make a GET request to an external API from a Google Apps Script using [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params). When I make this request with Postman or curl, I get back the expected response. However, when I try it with `UrlFetchApp`, I get back an empty response, `{}`.

I have tried using Basic Auth and OAuth 2, as well as explicitly setting the `oauthScopes` property in the manifest as described [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes).

I have confirmed with the API team that they are indeed sending back a full response when I hit the endpoint, but all I receive is `{}`. My problem seems similar to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57631757/blank-response-from-urlfetchapp-in-google-app-script) which went unanswered.

```
var headers = {
   "X-Client-Key": "KEY",
   "Authorization": "Bearer TOKEN"
};

var options = {
  method: "get",
  headers: headers,
}

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(ENDPOINT, options);
console.log(JSON.stringify(response));  // returns {}
```

Comment: What makes you think you only receive `{}`?

Comment: I was logging the response (updated the post). As @oleg-valter pointed out, this doesn't work correctly with an HTTPResponse object. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: If you use `Logger.log(response)` you will see all the response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not take what you see in logs at face value. `fetch` method of the `UrlFetchApp` service always returns an instance of [`HTTPResponse`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response) which is an object first and foremost. This is what the logs show you (I am assuming you are logging the `response` because this is the only context I am aware of where `{}` is displayed).

To extract useful information from the response, use the appropriate methods exposed on `HTTPResponse` instances, like [`getResponseCode`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getresponsecode) or [`getContentText`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getcontenttext).

Comment: You're right, using getContentText reveals I was getting a response back after all, just not the format I expected! Thank you for the education on the HTTPResponse methods.

Comment: @Lauren - no problem, sometimes the logs are not what they appear to be, it is better to follow the documentation on what would be returned/passed where - less error-prone. There was a question recently about logger showing `[[]]` while actually having data in the first array element, so be careful...